# How to add custom items to the Office 365 notification area?

Tags: office-365

How can I add custom items to the notification area in Office 365?

I'm working on a SharePoint Online application that has its own notification functionality. It seems obvious to get that integrated with the existing O365 notification functionality.

[image: Office 365 notification area]

Comment: You can use SP.UI.Notification if you only want to display notifications and not store them anywhere.

Comment: @Akhoy How does that work? Will the notification then appear in that menu?

Comment: No. it won't appear in the menu. Refer this for more info: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/creating-a-better-notification-for-custom-sharepoint-apps

Answer (score 1):

I found this link, [Outlook Push Notifications REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations), on MSDN. Hope this can be useful for you though there has been so much time since you asked the question.

This video explains how to use the API, [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/Introduction-to-Outlook-Notifications-REST-API).

Comment: Unless I missed something, this is all about Outlook, not the Office 365 notification area in general.

Comment: As far as I understand it, notifications are related with Outlook but also are cross all Office 365 area. I mean, the bell appears always and it's not about any Office 365 app, you can upload documents on a SharePoint site or you can be modifying a workflow on Microsoft Flow but the bell will be there for you, warning you if you have any task, email or any other element.